# How can I refresh a materialised view on SELECT in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a materialised view that aggregates another table.

I don't want to update the aggregated view on commit because it's rarely read.  Instead I would like to be able to update the materialised view when it is selected.  The only way I can think of do this is:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MY_VIEW', method=>'f');
END;
/

SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW;
```

Is there a better way of doing this in Oracle?

Comment: If you could use an "ordinary" view, you wouldn't have to refresh anything. That depends on how fast is access to data returned by materialized view's query. If it takes too long, then there's probably no use in using a view. But, then again, if you have to wait for it (the materialized view) to refresh, what's the difference?

Comment: @Littlefoot is right: if the MV doesn't take any time to refresh then there isn't any point to it - just use a normal view. If it does take time to refresh then you're not helping your performance if you only refresh on select - and there's still no point to having it. The only point to MVs is to refresh at some point *before* a select so that the user doesn't experience any wait time for the view computations, and so that multiple users can benefit from the same computations.